# Reliable/idempotent mailing from Azure Function app

Tags: c#, azure-functions, message-queue

I'm currently evaluating Azure Functions and I'm trying to find a way/pattern to reliable and idempotent send Emails (and store them in a db). I already read a lot about Sagas, 2PC, Eventual Consistency, but I don't know how to apply these concepts to my situation.

I already have a few business objects stored in a database. Now I would like to add an endpoint which e.g. sends a project summary based on a template. Therefore I created a http triggered function and a CreateEmail method. This is the pseudo code of it

```cs
public static async void CreateEmail(QueueClient queue, Guid id)
{
    // add the message to the queue, but keep it hidden for 3 min
    var sendReceipt = await queue.SendMessageAsync(id.ToString(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180))
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    //message.PopReceipt is now populated, and only this client can operate on the message until visibility timeout expires

    try
    {
        //Create the mail entity in the db and commit
        CreateEmailEntityAndCommit(id);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Delete the SendMail queue message, because an error occured in db operations
        queue.DeleteMessage(sendReceipt.Value.MessageId, sendReceipt.Value.PopReceipt);
        throw;
    }

    // Everything is fine. Mark the message as visible to the email send function
    queue.UpdateMessage(sendReceipt.Value.MessageId, sendReceipt.Value.PopReceipt,
        visibilityTimeout: TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

The code actually does not send the mail, but only creates a database entity and queues a message to the Azure Queue Storage. Another, queue triggered function picks up the messages, sends the mail and updates the status in the db:

```
public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items")]string id, ILogger log)
{
   if (CheckEmailStatus() == Status.Sent)
   {
       // Message received twice
       return;
   }

   SendEmail();
   UpdateEmailStatus(Status.Sent); // How do we deal with exceptions here? email sent successfully, but status not updated...
}
```

And here is my problem: If anything goes wrong immediately after sending the mail, the status is not updated. When azure delivers the message again, the Mail would be send again. I guess there is a pattern to avoid such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using storage queue, you need to handle idempotency or deduplication at the receiver function end using some identifier of the entity. For example, you can maintain a cache of ids which you can look up to check if currently received id exists, the cache can be set with a reasonable TTL of your desired time window.

Note: Duplicate detection is out of the box in [Service Bus queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection).

Also you might want to look at [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp).